# Does this series have a closed-form representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, closed-form

The following sum represents the number of relevant kinds of lines in an N-dimensional tic-tac-toe game, which is why I am interested in finding a closed form, but it also is the sum of all possible combinations of N unique elements when any number of the elements from 1 to N can be chosen, which is also cool, and seems like the kind of thing that would have an elegant transcendental form involving factorials and stuff.

$$
S = \sum_{j=1}^{N} {N! \over j!(N-j)!}, N \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}
$$

So is there an easy way to find a closed form here?

Comment: A combinatorial approach, BTW: your 'all possible combinations when any number of the elements can be chosen' is simply the set of all (non-empty) _subsets_ of $\{1\ldots N\}$; the size of the power set is the $2^N$ term (One easy way of seeing this is to represent subsets as a bit mask indicating which of the numbers $1\ldots N$ are in the subset) and your criterion of 'nonempty' accounts for the $-1$ correction.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks!  If that were an answer, I'd upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients) that $$\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{N!}{j!(N-j)!}=2^N$$
Your series $S$ is missing the first term, hence $$S=2^N-1$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\binom{N}{j}=\frac{N!}{j!(N-j)!}.$$

$$(1+x)^N=\sum_{j=0}^N\binom{N}{j}x^j.$$

$$S=(1+1)^N-\binom{N}{0}=2^N-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$S = 2^{N}-1$.
You can get this by noticing that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}\binom{N}{i} = (1+1)^{N} = 2^{N}$ by the binomial theorem.